Auto smooth stops working in 3D softwarw
Auto smooth doesn't work when I put my object in my 3D printer's software. The object appears as it did before smoothing it.

Hello and welcome. Smooth shading only affects the visual appearance of the model by adjusting how light interacts with the surface, it does not affect actual geometry. You have to add the subdivisions yourself and apply it.
